# Conflicting values in Desired State Configuration

Tags: azure, smb, dsc

When deploying our VM via ARM, a desired state configuration is executed.
There are 2 script resources that needs to map a SMB drive to the current user.
So both script resources need other ps credentials.

But I am getting the following error when executing:

```
Script MapVirtualDriveIcsUser
    {
        DependsOn = "[User]IcsUserAccount"
        GetScript = { return $false }
        TestScript = { return !(Test-Path Z:) }
        SetScript = {                             
                        New-PSDrive -Name Z -PSProvider FileSystem -Root "\\$($fileShareLocation)" -Credential $storageAccountCredentials -Persist -Scope Global                            
                    }   
        PsDscRunAsCredential = $icsCredentials      
    }

    Script MapVirtualDrivePartnerUser
    {
        DependsOn = "[User]PartnerUserAccount"
        GetScript = { return $false }
        TestScript = { return !(Test-Path Z:) }
        SetScript = {                             
                        New-PSDrive -Name Z -PSProvider FileSystem -Root "\\$($fileShareLocation)" -Credential $storageAccountCredentials -Persist -Scope Global                            
                    }   
        PsDscRunAsCredential = $vmPartnerCredentials        
    }

Following are the first few: The resources ('[Script]MapVirtualDriveIcsUser' and '[Script]MapVirtualDrivePartnerUser') have conflicting values of the following properties: 'PsDscRunAsCredential'.
```

How can this be solved?

Answer (score 0):

There is no "clean" way to resolve this. You should raise a bug, because it really is a bug. btw i think I've come across this some time ago.

Your best bet is to merge those into one script resource and pass in credentials or use same credentials on those steps.

https://powershell.org/forums/topic/salted-psdscrunascredentials-considered-conflicting-values/